# SharePoint List Calculated Column with multiple conditions

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I currently have two columns in a SharePoint List, "Due Date" and "Received Date". I would like to create a calculated column that shows a status of Complete, In Progress, or Overdue. If the "Due Date" column is in the past AND the "Received Date" column is blank, then the status would be Overdue. If the "Received Date" column has a date, then the status would be Complete. If the "Due Date" column is in the future and the "Received Date" column is blank, the status would be In Progress.

I have created a few practice columns that work, but I can't seem to put the formulas together in a way that works.

I have:
`=IF([Due Date]<TODAY(),"Overdue","In Progress")` this works but doesn't take into account the "Received Date" column.

`=IF(ISBLANK([Received Date]),"In Progress","Complete")` this works too but doesn't take into account the "Due Date" column.

Any idea of how I could combine these? Apologies if this is simple as I am very new to this.

Comment: Calculated columns will only be evaluated when an item is created or modified so any comparison to `TODAY` is probably not what you think it is. If you're trying to do that comparison at time of render, you can use List Formatting to accomplish this by comparing against the `@now` placeholder. Check out https://aka.ms/list-formatting for examples

Answer (score 0):

> =IF(ISBLANK([Received Date]),IF([Due Date]<TODAY(),"Overdue","In Progress"),"Complete")

This formula should basically do what you want. Below is my test result:
[image: Status formula]
[image: test result]